# Can't re-enter into cell edit mode with doubleclick after hitting enter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a simple DataGrid with the following column:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Column" Binding="{Binding ColumnValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsColumnEnabled}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Let's assume two rows, the second one is disabled. When I enter a value into the first cell and hit `Enter`, the focus doesn't jump to the next cell (because it's disabled). The problem is, I cannot enter into edit mode again with doubleclick until the current cell is focused.

[image]

Is there any trick to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a custom behaviour for <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses, you could override the `OnKeyDown` method in a custom class:

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            var currentCell = CurrentCell;
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (CurrentCell.Column.GetCellContent(CurrentCell.Item)?.Parent is DataGridCell cell && !cell.IsEnabled)
                CurrentCell = currentCell;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the root element of the `DataGrid` in your XAML:

```
<local:CustomerDataGrid ... />
```